# not able to read input file in storm spout

Tags: java, apache-storm

I have a Storm Spout that will read from a log file. So when I test the code locally its works well because I am passing run-time arguments while running the Job.

But when I am deploying the code in a cluster it gives a `FileNotFoundException`.

So my question is how to pass an input to a Spout in a cluster system.

I am using resource location to pass few Lookup tables to Bolts, but if I pass in the same way to Spout it gives the same error.

I also tried to pass the argument to `conf.put("logfile", args[0]);` in the driver class and the spout should read the conf object in its `open()` method. That also is not working.

```
public void open(Map conf, TopologyContext context, SpoutOutputCollector collector) {
        collector_out = collector;

        try {
            this.context = context;
            this.filereader = new FileReader(conf.get("logfile").toString());
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Error reading file ["+conf.get("logfile")+"]");
        }

}

public void nextTuple() {
    try {
        br = new BufferedReader(filereader);
        line = br.readLine();           
        while(line != null){
            count++;
            collector_out.emit(new Values(line));
            Thread.sleep(2);
            line = br.readLine();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    finally{
        completed = true;
    }
}
```

So if any idea how to get it going that would be a great help.

Comment: Could you put some code of your spout?

Comment: Storm cluster cannot recognize regular path. It's better use NFS or other alternatives.

Comment: you need to keep the file in some location which is accessible by all the nodes .. as suggested in the previous comments you can use NFS or equivalent ... to verify run storm in one node and keep the file there and you should be getting the expected output

Answer (score 1):

In cluster mode, when you reads a file in open method, each node goes to its local path and probably you don't have the file in all nodes.

Good option for solve this issue is mount nfs system in your cluster sharing a directory between the cluster nodes and put the files into that directory. I have an spout like yours working in this way.